# Jquery, add innerHTML to a DIV and access elements by ID of that innerHTML?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

**Script**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({   
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "list_controller.php",
        data    : "a=get&list_id=my_list",
        success : function(data){
            $('#list_container').innerHTML = data;
        }
    });                     
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="list_container"></div>
```

The `data` returned from the server contains a HTML with some clickable links which should trigger another jQuery function and reload `#list_container` DIV again :

```
<a href="#" value="a=edit&list_id=my_list&user=artur&id=110" id="adminlink">
    <img src="images/edit_user.png" />
</a>
```

I want these links to call other AJAX functions, f.ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#adminlink').click(function () {
        var val = $(this).attr("value");
        $.ajax({       
            type    : "POST",
            url     : "list_controller.php",
            data    : val,
            success : function(data){
                $('#list_container').innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
 });
```

The problem is that I'm not able to access the `#adminlink` anchor element that triggers the click function.

Everything else is working flawlessly, but any of the elements of the *innerHTML* dynamic `data` can't be accessed anymore.

Comment: $('body').on("click", "#adminlink", function(event){
    //dostuff
    });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're overwriting the contents of `#list_container`, the `#adminlink` on which you registered the handler is no longer the one on the page.

The simplest solution is event delegation, which relies on event bubbling:

```
$('#list_container').on('click', '#adminlink', function() { 
    ...
});
```

i.e. it's actually the static `#list_container` element that receives the `click` event, but jQuery then checks whether it was an element with ID `adminlink` that was actually clicked before invoking the required handler.

Always try to use the "closest" static ancestor element that you can when using event delegation.  In this case this would appear to be `#list_container`.  In the worst case you would end up using `document` but then the event has to bubble *all* the way up through the DOM before it can be processed.

Comment: With your latest edit now my answer looks like a complete duplicate. It took you long enough to use `#list_container` :)

Comment: @Alexander oh yeah - I hadn't noticed (honest) that you had used `#list_container` instead of `document`.